# When does bootstrapping for DI and Repositories become ridiculous?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am fairly new to DI and the Repository patterns and I can't help but feel I am missing something fundamental. I am working on a Azure Worker Role that is talking to three different data sources (Azure table storage, Visual Studio Online REST, and SharePoint/O365) and each worker role message ends up calling a mixture of about two dozen different tables, SharePoint lists, and VSO API's.

I am using the repository pattern [in this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Storage-Sample-5122a120) for abstracting out the untestable aspects of this project (namely Azure storage and SharePoint CSOM calls). It basically recommends creating a I(Type)Repository for each DAO.

Looking at how I am bootstrapping my IoC container (I am using SimpleInject, but I suspect I would have this problem with any IoC framework), I am registering nearly two dozen containers/services/implementations (whatever the right term is). Since the worker role will end up using each of these object types for each call this isn't like a MVC controller where the DI is only injecting for a couple of DAOs. I am wondering if I am falling into an anti-pattern or if its normal for really complicated, sequential methods to have a really long IoC bootstrapping process?

Comment: "It basically recommends creating a I(Type)Repository for each DAO.". I would say this is bad advice, because it results in SOLID principle violations. Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92). It discusses why the use of I(Type)Repository abstractions violates SOLID and how a better design looks like.

Comment: Thanks Steven, that helps tremendously.